# initialize vector of pairs

Tags: c++, templates, vector, std-pair

I wanted to initialize a vector of pairs with something like this

```
std::vector< std::pair<bool, bool> > myvector(initSequence.size(), X );
```

what shall I substitute in place of X, if I want to initialize every pair with (false, false)?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::pair<bool,bool>(false, false)
```

or

```
std::make_pair(false, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing.  `std::pair<bool, bool>` will be default constructed as `make_pair(false, false)`.