# How can I sort two vectors in the same way, with criteria that uses only one of the vectors?

Tags: c++, c++11

How can I sort two vectors in the same way, with criteria that uses only one of the vectors?

For example, suppose I have two vectors of the same size:

```
vector<MyObject> vectorA;
vector<int> vectorB;
```

I then sort `vectorA` using some comparison function. That sorting reordered `vectorA`. How can I have the same reordering applied to `vectorB`?

---

One option is to create a struct:

```
struct ExampleStruct {
    MyObject mo;
    int i;
};
```

and then sort a vector that contains the contents of `vectorA` and `vectorB` zipped up into a single vector:

```
// vectorC[i] is vectorA[i] and vectorB[i] combined
vector<ExampleStruct> vectorC;
```

This doesn't seem like an ideal solution. Are there other options, especially in C++11?

Comment: Can you perhaps provide an example with some input and the corresponding desired output? I am having troubles understanding the question

Comment: I think he wants to (effectively) sort the contents `vectorA` and `vectorB` both by the contents of `vectorB`.

Comment: I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874183/reusing-stdalgorithms-with-non-standard-containers/16905832) is a near duplicate if not an exact duplicate

Comment: What about sorting a third vector (of indices 0, ... vectorA.size()), based on the values in vectorA and "apply" those indices on vectorB? E.g. like in http://stackoverflow.com/a/10581051/417197

Comment: Personally, i'd rather have a `vector<pair<MyObject, int>>`.  Then you wouldn't have to worry about the two lists getting out of sync; one sort reorders both sets of data simultaneously.  And there's no extra struct to have to write.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

## Finding a sort permutation

Given a `std::vector<T>` and a comparison for `T`'s, we want to be able to find the permutation you would use if you were to sort the vector using this comparison.

```
template <typename T, typename Compare>
std::vector<std::size_t> sort_permutation(
    const std::vector<T>& vec,
    Compare& compare)
{
    std::vector<std::size_t> p(vec.size());
    std::iota(p.begin(), p.end(), 0);
    std::sort(p.begin(), p.end(),
        [&](std::size_t i, std::size_t j){ return compare(vec[i], vec[j]); });
    return p;
}
```

## Applying a sort permutation

Given a `std::vector<T>` and a permutation, we want to be able to build a new `std::vector<T>` that is reordered according to the permutation.

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> apply_permutation(
    const std::vector<T>& vec,
    const std::vector<std::size_t>& p)
{
    std::vector<T> sorted_vec(vec.size());
    std::transform(p.begin(), p.end(), sorted_vec.begin(),
        [&](std::size_t i){ return vec[i]; });
    return sorted_vec;
}
```

You could of course modify `apply_permutation` to mutate the vector you give it rather than returning a new sorted copy. This approach is still linear time complexity and uses one bit per item in your vector. Theoretically, it's still linear space complexity; but, in practice, when `sizeof(T)` is large the reduction in memory usage can be dramatic. ([See details](http://blog.merovius.de/2014/08/12/applying-permutation-in-constant.html))

```
template <typename T>
void apply_permutation_in_place(
    std::vector<T>& vec,
    const std::vector<std::size_t>& p)
{
    std::vector<bool> done(vec.size());
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (done[i])
        {
            continue;
        }
        done[i] = true;
        std::size_t prev_j = i;
        std::size_t j = p[i];
        while (i != j)
        {
            std::swap(vec[prev_j], vec[j]);
            done[j] = true;
            prev_j = j;
            j = p[j];
        }
    }
}
```

## Example

```
vector<MyObject> vectorA;
vector<int> vectorB;

auto p = sort_permutation(vectorA,
    [](T const& a, T const& b){ /*some comparison*/ });

vectorA = apply_permutation(vectorA, p);
vectorB = apply_permutation(vectorB, p);
```

## Resources

- [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)
- [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota)
- [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)
- [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap)
- [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)

Comment: In my compiler, I had to change "Compare& compare" to "Compare compare".

Comment: I needed also to include the header <numeric> in order to run std::iota function (vs2012).

Comment: "*You could of course modify `apply_permutation` to mutate the vector you give it rather than returning a new sorted copy.*" I would find fleshing this out, at least conceptually, a useful addition to the answer. Would you implement this in the same way as `apply_permutation` itself?

Comment: @ildjarn I've updated the answer with your suggestion.

Comment: How would you write this if you did not have C++11 available?

Comment: This code is great, thank you ! Just a remark, the function `apply_permutation_in_place` has a little bug in the implementation compared to the link given, that make it not apply a permutation properly. The error is in `std::swap(vec[i], vec[j]);` where `vec[i]` should be the previous value of `vec[j]` in the loop, and not constantly vec[i]. I spend time finding this error, so I hope this comment will help other people falling on the same problem ! `size_t oldJ = i;` should be added before the inner loop, vec[i] replaced by vec[oldJ], and oldJ = j; at the end of the inner loop

Comment: @beesleep Thank you for checking the code. :) Are you certain there is a bug? What is an example input for which it produces the wrong result?

Comment: Take a permutation vector  vector<size_t> p = {1, 3, 2, 0, 4, 5};, and apply p to {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. You are expecting, by definition, to find back the same values as p (0 on the third position, 1 in the 0, ...). If you test with your code, it is not the case. It's different from the implementation shown [here](http://blog.merovius.de/2014/08/12/applying-permutation-in-constant.html). You always switch vec[j] with  vec[i], i staying the same in the inner loop. In fact, the value in vec[i] when you enter the inner loop, need be swaped until it reach its final position. I hpoe I'm clear...

Comment: @beesleep Thank you for catching that. I fixed it.  Does it look correct now?

Comment: @TimothyShields , yep, now it works like a charm ! Thanks for correcting ;-)

Comment: One tiny improvement, if I may suggest, is to use [&vec] in the lambdas, better clarity.

Comment: There's a variation of apply_permutation (reorder in place), that doesn't require a third array of booleans, instead it "uncycles" the "cycles" in a permutation of sorted indices.. [sort 2 arrays according to one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44027808/sorting-two-arrays-based-on-one-with-standard-library-copy-steps-avoided/44030600#44030600) .

Comment: Got this compile error:
invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘main()::<lambda(const int&, const int&)>&’ from an rvalue of type ‘main()::<lambda(const int&, const int&)>’  [](int const& a, int const& b){ return a<b; });
Any ideas what I did wrong?
The vector I want to get the permutation is a vector<int>

Comment: Thanks for the excellent snippet! the sort_permutation declaration's `Compare& compare` should be const however. Otherwise you can't use std::less<T> or similar.

Comment: On VS2017, I had to change  `Compare& compare` to `Compare compare` to get it to compile.

Comment: When I find myself in this situation, usually I get out of this need by transforming from `std::vector<A>` + `std::vector<B>`. to `std::vector<std::pair<A,B>>`. Then you just need a comparison method that accepts two pairs. I know that's not what the question was, but it has prevented me from many headaches.

Comment: Templated lambdas are a C++20 feature, so the comparison lambda will need explicit types.

Answer (score 29):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), it is simple, sort a zip view:

```
std::vector<MyObject> vectorA = /*..*/;
std::vector<int> vectorB = /*..*/;

ranges::v3::sort(ranges::view::zip(vectorA, vectorB));
```

or explicitly use projection:

```
ranges::v3::sort(ranges::view::zip(vectorA, vectorB),
                 std::less<>{},
                 [](const auto& t) -> decltype(auto) { return std::get<0>(t); });
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/895ed99058eb347e)

Comment: Tried on VS2017, nothing compiled or worked, no matter what I tried. This library is known to work on VS2019, GCC and LLVM.

Comment: This is the solution! The whole point is to use O(1) space, while the other solutions allocate a spearate vector.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to contribute with a extension I came up with.
The goal is to be able to sort multiple vectors at the same time using a simple syntax.

```
sortVectorsAscending(criteriaVec, vec1, vec2, ...)
```

The algorithm is the same as the one Timothy proposed but using [variadic templates](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/variadic-templates-in-c/), so we can sort multiple vectors of arbitrary types at the same time.

Here's the code snippet:

```
template <typename T, typename Compare>
void getSortPermutation(
    std::vector<unsigned>& out,
    const std::vector<T>& v,
    Compare compare = std::less<T>())
{
    out.resize(v.size());
    std::iota(out.begin(), out.end(), 0);
 
    std::sort(out.begin(), out.end(),
        [&](unsigned i, unsigned j){ return compare(v[i], v[j]); });
}
 
template <typename T>
void applyPermutation(
    const std::vector<unsigned>& order,
    std::vector<T>& t)
{
    assert(order.size() == t.size());
    std::vector<T> st(t.size());
    for(unsigned i=0; i<t.size(); i++)
    {
        st[i] = t[order[i]];
    }
    t = st;
}
 
template <typename T, typename... S>
void applyPermutation(
    const std::vector<unsigned>& order,
    std::vector<T>& t,
    std::vector<S>&... s)
{
    applyPermutation(order, t);
    applyPermutation(order, s...);
}
 
template<typename T, typename Compare, typename... SS>
void sortVectors(
    const std::vector<T>& t,
    Compare comp,
    std::vector<SS>&... ss)
{
    std::vector<unsigned> order;
    getSortPermutation(order, t, comp);
    applyPermutation(order, ss...);
}
 
// make less verbose for the usual ascending order
template<typename T, typename... SS>
void sortVectorsAscending(
    const std::vector<T>& t,
    std::vector<SS>&... ss)
{
    sortVectors(t, std::less<T>(), ss...);
}
```

Test it in [Ideone](https://ideone.com/fork/QEAoqL).

I explain this a little bit better in [this blog post](https://tuket.github.io/posts/2017-09-30-sorting-multiple-vectors-in-the-same-way-using-c-variadic-templates/).

Answer (score 3):

## In-place sorting using permutation

I would use a permutation like Timothy, although if your data is too large and you don't want to allocate more memory for the sorted vector you should do it **in-place**. Here is a example of a O(n) (linear complexity)  **in-place sorting using permutation**:

*The trick is to get the permutation and the reverse permutation to know where to put the data overwritten by the last sorting step.*

```
template <class K, class T> 
void sortByKey(K * keys, T * data, size_t size){
    std::vector<size_t> p(size,0);
    std::vector<size_t> rp(size);
    std::vector<bool> sorted(size, false);
    size_t i = 0;

    // Sort
    std::iota(p.begin(), p.end(), 0);
    std::sort(p.begin(), p.end(),
                    [&](size_t i, size_t j){ return keys[i] < keys[j]; });

    // ----------- Apply permutation in-place ---------- //

    // Get reverse permutation item>position
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        rp[p[i]] = i;
    }

    i = 0;
    K savedKey;
    T savedData;
    while ( i < size){
        size_t pos = i;
        // Save This element;
        if ( ! sorted[pos] ){
            savedKey = keys[p[pos]];
            savedData = data[p[pos]];
        }
        while ( ! sorted[pos] ){
            // Hold item to be replaced
            K heldKey  = keys[pos];
            T heldData = data[pos];
            // Save where it should go
            size_t heldPos = rp[pos];

            // Replace 
            keys[pos] = savedKey;
            data[pos] = savedData;

            // Get last item to be the pivot
            savedKey = heldKey;
            savedData = heldData;

            // Mark this item as sorted
            sorted[pos] = true;

            // Go to the held item proper location
            pos = heldPos;
        }
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Though it looks like it is O(N^2), it is not. The inner while is only executed if the item is not sorted. As the inner while sorts the data, it kinda skips outer while iterations...

Answer (score 3):

I have recently wrote a proper zip iterator which works with the stl algorithms.
It allows you to produce code like this:

```
std::vector<int> a{3,1,4,2};
std::vector<std::string> b{"Alice","Bob","Charles","David"};

auto zip = Zip(a,b);
std::sort(zip.begin(), zip.end());

for (const auto & z: zip) std::cout << z << std::endl;
```

It is contained in a single header and the only requirement is C++17.
Check it out on [GitHub](https://github.com/dpellegr/ZipIterator).

There is also a post on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/231352/c17-zip-iterator-compatible-with-stdsort) which contains all the source code.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make a vector of pairs out of your individual vectors.
   [initialize vector of pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405630/initialize-vector-of-pairs)
   [Adding to a vector of pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897050/adding-to-a-vector-of-pair)
2. Make a custom sort comparator:
   [Sorting a vector of custom objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects)
   http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sort_using_a_custom_comparator#C.2B.2B
3. Sort your vector of pairs.
4. Separate your vector of pairs into individual vectors.
5. Put all of these into a function.

Code:

```
std::vector<MyObject> vectorA;
std::vector<int> vectorB;

struct less_than_int
{
    inline bool operator() (const std::pair<MyObject,int>& a, const std::pair<MyObject,int>& b)
    {
        return (a.second < b.second);
    }
};

sortVecPair(vectorA, vectorB, less_than_int());

// make sure vectorA and vectorB are of the same size, before calling function
template <typename T, typename R, typename Compare>
sortVecPair(std::vector<T>& vecA, std::vector<R>& vecB, Compare cmp)
{

    std::vector<pair<T,R>> vecC;
    vecC.reserve(vecA.size());
    for(int i=0; i<vecA.size(); i++)
     {
        vecC.push_back(std::make_pair(vecA[i],vecB[i]);   
     }

    std::sort(vecC.begin(), vecC.end(), cmp);

    vecA.clear();
    vecB.clear();
    vecA.reserve(vecC.size());
    vecB.reserve(vecC.size());
    for(int i=0; i<vecC.size(); i++)
     {
        vecA.push_back(vecC[i].first);
        vecB.push_back(vecC[i].second);
     }
}
```

Comment: vector of pairs of references?

Comment: I get what you mean, but pairs of references is not going to easily work.

Comment: @ruben2020: [It can](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper), but doing so just band-aids the issue.  If you have two pieces of data intertwined enough that sorting one should sort the other, it would seem that what you really have is a not-yet-integrated object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that vectorA and vectorB have equal lengths. You could create another vector, let's call it pos, where:

`pos[i] = the position of vectorA[i] after sorting phase`

and then, you can sort vectorB using pos, i.e create vectorBsorted where:

```
vectorBsorted[pos[i]] = vectorB[i]
```

and then vectorBsorted is sorted by the same permutation of indexes as vectorA is.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this works but i would use something like this. For example to sort two vectors i would use descending bubble sort method and vector pairs.

For descending bubble sort, i would create a function that requires a vector pair.

```
void bubbleSort(vector< pair<MyObject,int> >& a)
{
    bool swapp = true;
    while (swapp) {
        int key;
        MyObject temp_obj;
        swapp = false;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size() - 1; i++) {
            if (a[i].first < a[i + 1].first) {
                temp_obj = a[i].first;
                key = a[i].second;

                a[i].first = a[i + 1].first;
                a[i + 1].first = temp_obj;

                a[i].second = a[i + 1].second;
                a[i + 1].second = key;

                swapp = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After that i would put your 2 vector values into one vector pair. If you are able to add values at the same time use this one and than call the bubble sort function.

```
vector< pair<MyObject,int> > my_vector;

my_vector.push_back( pair<MyObject,int> (object_value,int_value));

bubbleSort(my_vector);
```

If you want to use values after adding to your 2 vectors, you can use this one and than call the bubble sort function.

```
vector< pair<MyObject,int> > temp_vector;

for (size_t i = 0; i < vectorA.size(); i++) {
            temp_vector.push_back(pair<MyObject,int> (vectorA[i],vectorB[i]));
        }

bubbleSort(temp_vector);
```

I hope this helps.
Regards,
Caner

Answer (score 0):

Based on Timothy Shields answer.
With a small tweak to `apply_permutaion` you can apply the permutation to multiple vectors of different types at once with use of a fold expression.

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
void apply_permutation(const std::vector<size_t>& perm, std::vector<T>& v, std::vector<Ts>&... vs) {

    std::vector<bool> done(v.size());
    for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        if(done[i]) continue;
        done[i] = true;
        size_t prev = i;
        size_t curr = perm[i];
        while(i != curr) {
            std::swap(v[prev], v[curr]);
            (std::swap(vs[prev], vs[curr]), ...);
            done[curr] = true;
            prev = curr;
            curr = perm[curr];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Want to add my solution too

suppose you have two vectors(or more):

```
vector<int> a;
vector<int> b;
...
```

create one additional vector *helper*:

```
vector<int> helper(v.size(),0);
std::iota(helper.begin(), helper.end(), 0);//fill it from 0 to the helper.size()-1 in ascending order
```

at this point you just should do a classic sort with custom comparator on helper vector:

```
sort(helper.begin(),helper.end(),[&](auto&i1, auto&i2){
    return a[i1]<a[i2];//basically you sort the helper based on values of a or whatever you need
});
```

now each element of helper will show what element should be in that place, like

```
if helper[0]==5 => element at index 5 should be at index 0
```

sorting others at this point is easy in +-linear time(not sure if implementation is linear but maybe it can be optimized:

```
for(int i=0;i<=helper.size();++i){
  int toSwapIndex=i;
  //if helper[i]==i, element is in place already, the code will continue to the next index
  while(helper[toSwapIndex]!=i){

    //here we try to find the pair where:
    //helper[toSwapIndex]==i, basically we are searching
    //for the element that is using what is currently at position [i]
    toSwapIndex=helper[toSwapIndex];
  }
  //we put at position [i] the element that should be here AND
  //we move what's at position [i] to the position helper[i]
  swap(a[i],a[helper[i]]);
  ...//do other vector swaps here

  //now we need to fix a problem we created:
  //remember the *toSwapIndex* that was using position [i]?
  //we moved that to the position helper[i] and as consequence
  //we should update the helper[toSwapIndex] to point towards helper[i]
  swap(helper[i],helper[toSwapIndex]);
  
  //as result, at position i the correct element is placed
}
```