# How to apply permutation to std::map values

Tags: c++, c++11, permutation, stdvector, stdmap

I have a `std::vector<T>` and a `std::map<U, std::size_t>`, where the map acts as a different way to index the vector, i.e. the value in a key-value pair of the map is the index of a vector element.
I can guarantee that not only the keys, but also the values of the map are unique.

Now when I apply a std::sort to the vector, that obviously changes the indices under which elements can be found, and I'd like to update my map accordingly.

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17074810/794740) answer for applying a permutation to a second vector. What I want to do is apply this permutation to the values of the map.

The following code does work, but is of course terribly inefficient

```
template <typename T, typename U>
std::vector<T> apply_permutation(const std::vector<T>& vec,
                                 std::map<U, std::size_t>& m,
                                 const std::vector<std::size_t>& p)
{
    std::vector<T> sorted_vec(vec.size());
    std::transform(p.begin(), p.end(), sorted_vec.begin(),
                   [&](std::size_t i){ return vec[i]; });
    for (std::size_t i(0); i != p.size(); ++i)
        for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)
            if (it->second == p[i])
                it->second = i;

    return sorted_vec;
}
```

I'm looking for a more efficient way to keep the vector and map in sync.

Comment: consider boost::multiindex.

Comment: You are right that reconsidering the design of these two indices is worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say we start with this:

```
vector<char> v1{'b', 'c', 'a'};
map<char, size_t> m{{'b', 0}, {'c', 1}, {'a', 2}};
```

If we iterate the map from `begin()` to `end()`, we would get:

```
  {'a', 2}
  {'b', 0}
  {'c', 1}
```

since a **map sorts the elements on key**.

Now, if you sort the vector, it becomes

```
vector<char> v2{'a', 'b', 'c'};
```

At this point, you can just iterate over the map and change the indices

```
size_t index = 0;
for (auto& elem : m) {
  assert(elem.first == v2[index]);
  elem.second = index++;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, because you assume T=U, which is not the case in my problem

Comment: @Philipp: I see. How are T and U related, if any? Can you provide an example please?