# Sorting vectors based on another vector

Tags: c++, sorting, opencv, stdvector

Let's suppose I have the following three vectors:

```
std::vector<int> classIds;
std::vector<float> confidences;
std::vector<Rect> boxes;
```

The data is pushed into these vectors as follows:

```
for (iterate over candidates)
{
    // compute classIdPoint
    if (confidence > confidence_Threshold)
    {
        // compute left, top, width, and height
        classIds.push_back(classIdPoint.x);
        confidences.push_back((float)confidence);
        boxes.push_back(Rect(left, top, width, height));
    }
}
```

The order at which the data is pushed in ties these vectors together. For instance, the confidence value in `confidences.at(0)` corresponds to the class ID at `classIds.at(0)`.

Now I want to sort the `confidences` vector in descending order, which is easy to do

```
sort(confidences.begin(), confidences.end(), greater<float>());
```

But now I need the same sorting to be applied to the other two vectors (`classIds` and `boxes`) in order to maintain the relationship between the vectors. What would be a good way of doing this?

Comment: can you use one vector of structs instead?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074324/how-can-i-sort-two-vectors-in-the-same-way-with-criteria-that-uses-only-one-of/46506051

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I sort two vectors in the same way, with criteria that uses only one of the vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074324/how-can-i-sort-two-vectors-in-the-same-way-with-criteria-that-uses-only-one-of)