# How do I sort multiple vectors based on the values of one of them?

Tags: sorting, vector, rust

I have three vectors of the same length; `A`, `B`, and `C`. I want to sort `A`, and then apply the same reordering to `B` and `C`.

This is what `A`, `B`, and `C` might contain:

```
A = 0, 120, 72, 48, 96, 24, 96, 48, 0, 0
B = 0.000818, -0.014796, 0.028391, -0.001460, 0.007406, 0.020932, 0.007412, 0.034635, -0.023112, -0.023108
C = 3, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 0, 1
```

This is the expected result:

```
A = 0, 0, 0, 120, 24, 48, 48, 72, 96, 96
B = 0.000818, -0.023112, -0.023108, -0.014796, 0.020932, -0.001460, 0.034635, 0.028391, 0.007406, 0.007412
C = 3, 0, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3
```

(I don't necessarily need the ordering to be stable as it is in this example)

When searching for this problem, the only results I found were for other programming languages ([C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074324/how-can-i-sort-two-vectors-in-the-same-way-with-criteria-that-uses-only-one-of), [Python](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+sort+multiple+lists+by+one)). I was unable to translate the C++ solution into Rust because I'm unfamiliar with C++.

I *was* able to translate the Python version:

```rust
use itertools::izip;

let a = &[0, 120, 72, 48, 96, 24, 96, 48, 0, 0];
let b = &[0.000818, -0.014796, 0.028391, -0.001460, 0.007406, 0.020932, 0.007412, 0.034635, -0.023112, -0.023108];
let c = &[3, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 0, 1];

let mut zipped_vectors: Vec<_> = izip!(a, b, c).collect();
zipped_vectors.sort_by_key(|tuple| tuple.0);
let a: Vec<_> = zipped_vectors.iter().map(|tuple| tuple.0).collect();
let b: Vec<_> = zipped_vectors.iter().map(|tuple| tuple.1).collect();
let c: Vec<_> = zipped_vectors.iter().map(|tuple| tuple.2).collect();
```

However, this is not very efficient which is a problem because efficiency is of utmost importance in my application.

How can you perform this operation *efficiently* in Rust?

Comment: Note that duplicates are not bad — now anyone who searches for the keywords you used that aren't in the duplicate will find the duplicate _because_ of this post.