# use std::sort compare function to sort corresponding other vector elements

Tags: c++

I'm having 2 vectors one of type `int32_t` which corresponds to age of the students and another of type `std::string` which corresponds to name of the students. I want to sort the students based on ages(descending) and reflect the sort changes in student names list as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


void print(const std::vector<int32_t>& student_age_list, const std::vector<std::string>& student_name_lsit) {
    int32_t size = student_age_list.size();
    for(int32_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        std::cout << "Name: " << student_name_lsit[i] << ", Age: " << student_age_list[i] << "\n";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int32_t main(int32_t argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<int32_t> student_age_list { 23, 56, 34, 77, 23, 66, 54, 34 };
    std::vector<std::string> student_name_list { "abc", "sjdg", "gdagd", "twue", "sgfdah", "tywet", "mbmdas", "uyqwteu" };
    
    print(student_age_list, student_name_list);
    
    std::sort(student_age_list.begin(), student_age_list.end(), [](const int32_t& a, const int32_t& b) { return a > b; });
    
    std::cout << "\nAfter sort\n\n";
    print(student_age_list, student_name_list);
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Why 2 vectors? There is no way to correspond the 2 data sets together, so sorting one will get out of sync with the other. Why not 1 vector instead, holding elements of a struct/class type? That way, student info is kept together as a single unit of data.

Comment: actually input is given to me as two separate lists

Comment: Still, it doesn't stop you from storing it as a single vector of structures.

Comment: I know I can create another vector like `std::vector<std::pair<int32_t, std::string>>` and sort based on the first element of the pair. But this unnecessarily consumes extra space. So just in search of better way of doing it

Comment: @Harry having 1 vector of pairs does not use more memory than 2 separate vectors of the same data. What you are attempting to do can’t be done the way you have shown it. You need to either consolidate the data into 1 vector, or use a 3rd vector to link the other 2 vectors together.

Comment: @Harry The vector of pairs would be *instead* of the two separate ones, not in addition to them.

Answer (score 0):

Given the code you have shown, there is simply no way to correlate the age data with the name data, so sorting one vector will get out of sync with the other vector.

You should use 1 vector instead. Create a `struct`/`class` to hold each student’s data, and then use 1 vector for that data. For example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct StudentInfo
{
    std::string name;
    int32_t age;
};

void print(const std::vector<StudentInfo>& student_list) {
    for(const auto &student : student_list)
        std::cout << "Name: " << student.name << ", Age: " << student.age << "\n";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<StudentInfo> student_list { {“abc”,23}, {“sjdg”,56}, {“gdagd”,34}, {“twue”,77}, {“sgfdah”,23}, {“tywet”,66}, {“mbmdas”,54}, {“uyqwteu”,34} };
    
    print(student_list);
    
    std::sort(student_list.begin(), student_list.end(), [](const StudentInfo& a, const StudentInfo& b) { return a.age > b.age; });
    
    std::cout << "\nAfter sort\n\n";
    print(student_list);
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/axTkdN)

If that is not an option for you, for whatever reason, then you will have to link the 2 vector datas together somehow. For instance, you could use a 3rd vector holding indexes into the other 2 vectors, and then sort the indexes instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void print(const std::vector<int32_t>& student_age_list, const std::vector<std::string>& student_name_list, const std::vector<size_t>& student_index_list) {
    for(size_t index : student_index_list)
        std::cout << "Name: " << student_name_list[index] << ", Age: " << student_age_list[index] << "\n";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<int32_t> student_age_list { 23, 56, 34, 77, 23, 66, 54, 34 };
    std::vector<std::string> student_name_list { "abc", "sjdg", "gdagd", "twue", "sgfdah", "tywet", "mbmdas", "uyqwteu" };
    std::vector<size_t> student_index_list { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    
    print(student_age_list, student_name_list, student_index_list);
    
    std::sort(student_index_list.begin(), student_index_list.end(), [&](const size_t& a, const size_t& b) { return student_age_list[a] > student_age_list[b]; });
    
    std::cout << "\nAfter sort\n\n";
    print(student_age_list, student_name_list, student_index_list);
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/P0j5bx)

Comment: to generate the index vector use `std::iota(student_index_list.begin(), student_index_list.end(), 0);` [How can I sort two vectors in the same way, with criteria that uses only one of the vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17074810/995714)

Comment: @phuclv you could use `iota`, this was just an example.