# How can i sort vector of vectors by other vector

Tags: sorting, oop, c++20

I am making a genetic algorithm and I have a sorting problem:
I have such a class, it is represented as std::vector

```
class GA_Class {
public:
float Fitness = 0.0f;

bool Parent = 0;
};

typedef std::vector<GA_Class> GA_Vector;
```

Also I have a main class

```
class GA_Population {
private:
std::vector<std::vector<ZydisDisassembledInstruction>> PopulationSetInstrs;
GA_Vector PopulationParametrs;
private:
bool FitnessSort(size_t Unit);
public:
void FitnessSorting();
};
```

My problem is contained in the following:
I need somehow to sort the vectors of the variable `std::vector<std::vector<ZydisDisassembledInstruction>> PopulationSetInstrs;` by `GA_Vector PopulationParametrs;`

I made such an implementation

```
    bool GA_Population::FitnessSort(size_t Unit)
    {
        return (PopulationParametrs[Unit].Fitness < PopulationParametrs[Unit].Fitness);
    }

    void GA_Population::FitnessSorting()
    {
        std::sort(PopulationSetInstrs.begin(), PopulationSetInstrs.end(), FitnessSort);

        //for (size_t Unit = 0; Unit < PopulationSetInstrs.size(); ++Unit)
        //{
        //  std::sort(PopulationSetInstrs[Unit].begin(), PopulationSetInstrs[Unit].end(), FitnessSort);
        //}
    }
```

But I need to iterate somehow along the `PopulationParametrs` vector with the same iterator that `PopulationSetInstrs` has

Or do I need to redo the `GA_Population` class in some other way? I just need to contain instructions for the `ZydisDisassembledInstruction` class in the vector and add this from the `GA_Class`

```
float Fitness = 0.0f;

bool Parent = 0;
```

p.s.
Please don't beat me with piss rags. I'm not good at programming in C++

Comment: [How can I sort two vectors in the same way, with criteria that uses only one of the vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074324/how-can-i-sort-two-vectors-in-the-same-way-with-criteria-that-uses-only-one-of) may help get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I redid my classes and used range(https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3)

Class

```
class GA_Population {
    private:
        std::vector<std::vector<ZydisDisassembledInstruction>> PopulationSetInstrs;
        //GA_Vector PopulationParametrs;
        std::vector<long double> svFitness;
        std::vector<bool> Parentness;
    public:
        inline void FitnessSorting();
    };
```

Method:

```
    inline void GA_Population::FitnessSorting()
    {
        ranges::v3::sort(ranges::view::zip(svFitness, PopulationSetInstrs),
            std::less<>{},
            [](const auto& t) -> decltype(auto) { return std::get<0>(t); });
    }
```